# Recover modem from AT+CEER 388

Tags: at-command, modem

#### CEER 388 Issue

We are using an Lara R211 modem an are experiencing issues where calls start to fail after some time due to the following CEER error:

`AT+CEER?`

`+CEER: "CC setup error", 388, "CS connection release triggered by MM"`

We tried to change the carrier but that does not work anymore (`AT+COPS`).  The only way to recover the modem seems to be resetting it (via pin).

#### Questions

1. What is the proper way to recover from `CEER 388`? Is there anything we try to do or is resetting the modem the appropriate approach here?
2. What is the actual root cause for this failure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were never able to fully fixed the underlaying issue but have been able to find a workaround that mitigates the issues we were facing:

- We switched from a `python-modem` fork to using `modem-manager`.
- Using `modem-manager` allowed us to reset the modem much faster (i.e. for CEER 388).
- We added a retry mechanism for unsuccessful calls (for selected CEERs).

Answer (score 1):

> +CEER: "CC setup error", 388, "CS connection release triggered by MM"

I'll decode this from my mobile phone development experience. CC is Call Control, and is a "block"/entity defined in the GSM standards for handling setting up and tearing down Circuit Switched calls (CS). This includes sending and receiving call control messages like SETUP and ALERTING. I think CC is interfacing only the BTS in the network.

While you maybe could in theory implement a phone/modem without having a specific CC entity (as long as other parts handle the required responsibility), in practice everybody has some CC entity. GSM allowed up til 8 active calls simultaneously (e.g. one active and some other calls on hold (maybe multiparty has also in the mix here?)), CC is managing those.

MM is [Mobility Management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobility_management), another entity specified in the GSM standards, responsible for monitoring the location the phone/modem is in, registers its presence with the network, and provide the network with information. It also is involved in switching between base stations when the phone/modem moves around.

As for the actual 338 error, some values are standardized, but many are manufacturer specific, and I think this one is, thus you need to get hold of the official AT command document describing Lara R211 to say for sure.

So the problem seems to be related to your sim/subscription and the network, try to use a different sim card and see if it behaves identical. Since things start out ok but fails over time this might be bugs in the modem and/or network, and if resetting works you have a workaround. You might be able to just detach from the network and attach again instead of doing a hard reset.